# CouchDB "last_seq" number changes when adding since=now

Tags: couchdb, fauxton, couchdb-fauxton

I am getting inconsistent results from CouchDB version 3.2.1.

If I get a list of changes in a database by calling `http://docdb.mycouchdb.com/my_database/_changes` I get a long list of changes in "results" with the final "seq" value matching what I get in "last_seq":

```
{"results":[
{"seq":"1-g1AAAABPeJzLYWBgYMxgTmEQTM4vTc5ISXIwNDLXMwBCwxygFFMiQx4Lw38gyMpgTmTMBQqxGxiaWRilJmHTkgUAFM4Udw","id":"_design/timestampsviews","changes":[{"rev":"1-72c0e9b448985fd65beb3cc3a580c588"}]},
.
.
.
{"seq":"330-g1AAAABSeJzLYWBgYMxgTmEQTM4vTc5ISXIwNDLXMwBCwxygFFMiQx4Lw38gyMpgTgIq9coFirIbGJpZGKUmYdOVBQBEcxTC","id":"fa3441f98a6643810cd8925d6491ef9f","changes":[{"rev":"1-88db0df4d97e2004c00c87c030bda7b5"}]}
],
"last_seq":"330-g1AAAABSeJzLYWBgYMxgTmEQTM4vTc5ISXIwNDLXMwBCwxygFFMiQx4Lw38gyMpgTgIq9coFirIbGJpZGKUmYdOVBQBEcxTC","pending":0}
```

However if I do `http://docdb.mycouchdb.com/my_database/_changes?since=now` (ie. add "?since=now") because I only want to get "last_seq" I get a completely different value which did not appear in the previous list:

```
{"results":[

],
"last_seq":"333-g1AAAABSeJzLYWBgYMxgTmEQTM4vTc5ISXIwNDLXMwBCwxygFFMiQx4Lw38gyMpgTgIq9c0FirIbGJpZGKUmYdOVBQBE2RTF","pending":0}
```

Any idea what is going on here? Is this a bug?

I would expect one of two things.

Surely either `http://docdb.mycouchdb.com/my_database/_changes` should have a couple more entries in "results" and end with `"last_seq":"333-g1AAAABSeJzLYWBgYMxgTmEQTM4vTc5ISXIwNDLXMwBCwxygFFMiQx4Lw38gyMpgTgIq9c0FirIbGJpZGKUmYdOVBQBE2RTF"`

or `http://docdb.mycouchdb.com/my_database/_changes?since=now` should end with `"last_seq":"330-g1AAAABSeJzLYWBgYMxgTmEQTM4vTc5ISXIwNDLXMwBCwxygFFMiQx4Lw38gyMpgTgIq9coFirIbGJpZGKUmYdOVBQBEcxTC"`

In other words, consistency ... so that "last_seq" is the same regardless of how you called it, or am I missing something here?